# Ios 8 фиксация ориентации view

Tags: xcode, ios

Как теперь в ios 8 фиксируют нужную ориентацию в отдельном view? подскажите пжст код на обьектив си!старые методы работают с косяками

Comment: Нашел viewwilltransitiontosize кто нибудь знает как им пользоваться?

Comment: только в отдельном UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Добавил код и все получилось

```
 CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;

// Real Size + 0.000001
self.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width+0.000001, frame.size.height+0.000001);
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```